# Cannot encode type ([object Object]) to a Firestore Value error while attempting pagination

Tags: firebase, pagination, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

So here I have my code

```
notifull.get('/getNote', (request, response) => {

// START Get variables
var requestData = {
    // location properties
    subject: request.query.subject,
    category: request.query.category,
    subcategory: request.query.subcategory,

    // easy way to get full reference string
    referenceString: function() {
        return `${this.subject}/${this.category}/${this.subcategory}`;
    },

    // pagination properties
    pagePosition: Number(request.query.pagePosition),

    // easy way to get limit number

    paginationNumber: function() {
        return (this.pagePosition - 1) * 2;
    }
};

// DEBUG_PURPOSES response.send(requestData.referenceString());

// END Get variables 


// START Construct index
var first = admin.firestore().collection(requestData.referenceString())
    .orderBy("upvotes")
    .limit(requestData.paginationNumber());

// DEBUG_PURPOSES response.send(first)

// END Construct index

// START Paginate
return first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
    // Get the last visible document
    var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
    console.log("last", lastVisible);

    // Construct a new query starting at this document,
    // get the next 25 cities.
    var next = admin.firestore().collection(requestData.referenceString())
            .orderBy("upvotes")
            .startAfter(lastVisible)
            .limit(2);

    response.send(next)
});

});
```

As you can see, I am attempting to Paginate using Cloud Firestore. If you'll notice, I've divided the code into sections, and the previous testing shows me the Construct Index and Get variables sections work. However, when I pulled the Paginate example from Firebase's own docs, adapted it to my code, and then tried to run, I was met with this error.

```
 Cannot encode type ([object Object]) to a Firestore Value
```

UPDATE: After more testing, it seems that if I remove the startAfter line, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to firebase documentation, Objects of custom classes are not supported so in some languages like PHP, C++, Python and Node.js.

PLEASE HERE AS A REFERENCE.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects

So, I can advise to encode your objects to json and be decoding them to your custom classes when you download them from firebases.